# How to write a prisma schema and use it with trpc

Tags: reactjs, database, next.js, prisma, trpc.io

I am learning the T3 stack and have never used prisma or trpc.  The schema is based on a social media model.  It has users, post, and likes. I think I am on the right path, but seeing how I have never used this before, I am completely lost.

I tried to make a model for likes, and what I am trying to accomplish is that each user can like a post, but if the post has already been liked by the user, it can not be liked again.  The way a normal social media site would work.

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  post          Post[]
}
```

```
model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  message   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @default(now())
  userId    String
  author    User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  likes     Likes[]
}
```

```
model Likes {
  id     String @id @default(cuid())
  likes  Int    @default(0)
  postId String
  post   Post   @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
}
```

trpc

```
likePosts: protectedProcedure
    .input(z.string())
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      return await ctx.prisma.likes.create({
        where: {
          id: input,
        },
        data: {
          likes: { increment: 1 },
        },
      });
    }),
```

When I try this, i get the following error

Invalid `prisma.likes.update()` invocation:

An operation failed because it depends on one or more records that were required but not found. Record to update not found.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that does the `update`?

You might be updating data that does not yet exist. Like if you try to update a non-existing like.